# Access view from anywhere without using static declaration

Tags: java, android, class, view, static

I have a bit experience in java for android development but I have some questions that is not very clear to me.

I have a ViewPager for screen slide, inside my fragment I have buttons that can switch from one screen to another.

What I did is, in my MainActivity, I declared my ViewPager as `static`, so I was allowed to use the `setCurrentItem(int position)` from anywhere.

But I learned that declaring a View as static is not a good practice since it would exist "forever" in the memory (as soon as the app is alive). But I though a new approach and I would like to know if it is better or not than using static Views.

Lets say I have the following:

```
public void MainActivity extends Activity{

    public static ViewPager pager;

    //code...
}
```

Then, on my Fragment class:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

        //code...

        private void changePage(int position){
            MainActivity.pager.setCurrentItem(position);
        }
    }
```

I though to create a class that extends the MainActivity, then I don't need the ViewPager to be static but only public, then I would call this class inside `MyFragment` and change the page. See:

```
public class PageControl extends MainActivity{

    private void setCurrentPage(int position){
        pager.setCurrentItem(position);
    }

}
```

Then, my `changePage(int position)` method inside `MyFragment` would be:

```
private void changePage(int position){
    PageControl mPageControl = new PageControl(); //Of course this line would be on onCreate()
    mPageControl.setCurrentPage(position);
}
```

I'm asking this because I'm afraid to have a lot of "information" inside my `PageControl` class since it is extending the `MainActivity`, but this way looks better because I could even create a listener for page changes inside PageControl and easily handle what I want.

So: keep my `ViewPager` as `static` or I should create the `PageControl` to manage my page changes? Any suggestions how I could do this, instead of these options I said?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is to make a base class for your activities, add a method to update the instance view, then extend the base class.  Something like this:

```
public class ActvityBase extends Activity{

    ...

    public void changePagerPosition(int position){
         this.pager.setCurrentItem(position);
    }

}

public MainActivity extends ActivityBase{

    ...

}
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

    ...

    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).changePagerPosition(position);

}
```

Comment: Hmm, good, this is a very simple solution, this is what I was looking for, thanks for your advice. +1

Answer (score 2):

You can simply define a callback `Interface` which your `MainActivity` implements. Just pass the `MainActivity` instance to the `Fragment` either as constructor parameter or some other defined method which takes as argument the `Interface` type. Then inside your `Fragment` call the implemented method when you need to slide to another page. This way you dont have to get the reference of the `ViewPager` inside the `Fragment`.

You can also do this:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

    private ArrayList<ChangePageListener> listeners = new ArrayList<ChangePageListener>();

    public addChangePageListener(ChangePageListener listener){
         if(!listeners.contains(listener){
             listeners.add(listener);
         }
    }

    public removeChangePageListener(ChangePageListener listener){
         if(listeners.contains(listener){
             listeners.remove(listener);
         }
    }

    private void changePage(int position)
    {
         for(ChangePageListener listener: listeners){
              listener.changePage(position);
         }
    }

}

public interface ChangePageListener{
    public void changePage(int position);
}

public MainActivity extends Activity implements ChangePageListener{

    public void changePage(int position){
        this.pager.setCurrentItem(position);
    }

}
```

Comment: Md. Arafat Al Mahmud, thank you for your suggestion, creating a interface looks interesting, I'll learn more about it and how I could use this. What jcw suggested looks more viable in my case, but I gave you up vote. Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to pass the MainActivityReference, nor should you.  Simply add addPageChangeListener() and removePageChangeListener() methods to the Fragment, then call addPageChangeListener(this) from the Activity.

Comment: Actually according to the question title "Access view from anywhere without using static declaration" I wanted to suggest a generic solution. Defining callback interface and passing the reference will work in any situation whether it is Activity or not. :)

Comment: @Md.ArafatAlMahmud I've edited your question to show what I mean.  If you don't like it, let me know and I'll undo the edit.